# randint() unexpected behavior

Tags: python, math

I'm writing a python script to find out some things about randomization.

I have the following code:

```
from random import randint

one = 0
two = 0

olddiff = 0
diff = 0

sumdiff = 0
avgdiff = 0

headcounter = 0
counter = 0


while (headcounter < 500000):
    while (counter < 500):
        x = randint(1,2)
        if(x==1):
            one += 1
        else:
            two += 1

        counter+=1

    if (one > two):
        diff = one - two
    else:
        diff = two - one

    sumdiff += diff

    if(diff > olddiff):
        olddiff = diff

    headcounter +=1


avgdiff = sumdiff / 500000


print "Occurences of 1: %d" % (one)
print "Occurences of 2: %d" % (two)
print "After 500000 calculations, the max difference found is %d" % (olddiff)
print "Sum of the differences is %d" % (sumdiff)
print "The average difference is %d" % (avgdiff)
```

I am however getting this unexpected output:

First try:

```
Occurences of 1: 262
Occurences of 2: 238
After 500000 calculations, the max difference found is 24
Sum of the differences is 24000
The average difference is 24
```

Second try:

```
Occurences of 1: 247
Occurences of 2: 253
After 500000 calculations, the max difference found is 6
Sum of the differences is 3000000
The average difference is 6
```

Third try:

```
Occurences of 1: 252
Occurences of 2: 248
After 500000 calculations, the max difference found is 4
Sum of the differences is 2000000
The average difference is 4
```

Etc...

In 50 times i've run it, there's never a difference between the max difference and the average difference. This is also every time the current difference.

Is there something wrong with my code or is this expected because of the mechanisms behind the randint() function?

Comment: Hi Martijn, Sorry, that wasn't the intention. I revised the script and saw exactly what the problem was so I deleted the question without refreshing the page! 

Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset the `counter` in the loop, so you only calculated the `one` and `two` values **once**. The other 499999 runs you re-use the same `one` and `two` counts, because the `while (counter < 500)` condition remains `False`.

You can easily see the effect in the `one` and `two` counts; they only add up to 500.